# How to remove this recursion that uses completable future

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, tail-recursion, completable-future

I initially wrote this piece of code because this is how I see the world, but I would like to investigate how I could remove the recursion.

The idea is that I have a list of instructions that I want to render. The renderer is giving me a completable future on a result for only one instruction. The result may not be valid some time, so I want to call the renderer on the next instruction. I want to return the first instruction that renders a valid result.

I would like to ask a tierce person to have a look and give me some ideas if possible.

```
/**
 * I want a a completable future for a list of instructions, returning
 * me the first valid result for the instruction input.
 */ 
private CompletableFuture<Result> getFutureResult(final List<Instruction> instructions) {
    final CompletableFuture<Result> futureResult = new CompletableFuture<>();
    renderAux(futureResult, instructions.iterator());
    return futureResult;
}

/**
 * This is actually an external method that will return a completable
 * future for only one instruction. I cannot modify this API.
 */
private CompletableFuture<Result> render(final Instruction instruction) {
    /.../
}

/**
 * This method is called recursively for the current instruction in the
 * the iterator, if the result if not valid, we call on the next instruction.
 */
private void renderAux(
        final CompletableFuture<Result> futureResult,
        final Iterator<Instruction> instructionIterator) {

    final Instruction instruction = instructionIterator.next();
    final boolean isLast = !instructionIterator.hasNext();
    render(instruction).whenComplete((result, e) -> {
        if (result.isValid() || isLast) {
            // Complete the future on the first valid result, or
            // if this is the last instruction.
            futureResult.complete(result);
        } else {
            // Recursive call for the next instruction.
            renderAux(futureResult, instructionIterator);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi,I have given my solution,I wish it to helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just chain the futures together directly using the [`CompletableFuture.handle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
private CompletableFuture<Result> getFutureResult(final List<Instruction> instructions) {
    CompletableFuture<Result> futureResult = null;

    for (Instruction instruction : instructions) {
        if (futureResult == null) {
            futureResult = render(instruction);
        } else {
            futureResult = futureResult.handle((result, e) -> {
                if (result.isValid())
                    return result;
                else
                    return render(instruction).join();
            });
        }
    }

    return futureResult;
}
```

This creates an additional future for every instruction in your list but still doesn't execute more instructions than necessary.

Comment: If you don't handle exceptions, you should use `thenApply` instead of `handle`.

Comment: Or use `thenCompose`: `futureResult = futureResult.thenCompose(result -> result.isValid()? CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result): render(instruction));`

Comment: @Holger I see you again,inspired by your comment,I solved his problem by using `CompletableFuture.thenCombine`

Answer (score 0):

Something you are doing like as [CompletableFuture.anyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#anyOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) but completing the future with your own condition so I called my method as `anyOf`.I have implemented two versions of `anyOf`, one matching the result in sequence, and another matching the result in parallel.After implementing my own `anyOf` method in deep I found the interesting thing is CompletableFuture like as [ES2015 Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)/[jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/).

### Usage

```
private CompletableFuture<Result> getFutureResult(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    return anyOf(instructions,this::render,Result::isValid);
}
```

If you want fetch a valid result from instructions in sequence,then you can use sync approach as below:

> the sequence algorithm implemented by [CompletableFuture.thenCombine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method.

```
private <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> anyOf(List<T> items
        , Function<T, CompletableFuture<R>> promiseMapping
        , Predicate<R> condition) {

    CompletableFuture<R> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    for (T it : items) {
        result = result.thenCombine(promiseMapping.apply(it), (own, other) -> {
            if (own != null && condition.test(own)) {
                return own;
            }
            return condition.test(other) ? other : null;
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you want fetch a valid result from instructions in parallel regardless of which valid result returned,then you can use non-sync approach as below,for more details to see the **Tests** section:

> the parallel algorithm implemented by [CompletableFuture.thenCompose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) method.

```
private <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> anyOf(List<T> items
        , Function<T, CompletableFuture<R>> promiseMapping
        , Predicate<R> condition) {
    return items.parallelStream()
            .map(promiseMapping)
            .map(completeWhenMatching(condition))
            .reduce(doneWhenAnyCompleted())
            .orElse(completedFuture(null));
}
```

### Test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.*;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

public class AnyOfCompletableFutureTest {
    private static final RuntimeException CHECKING_ERROR = new RuntimeException("It can't be checked!");
    private static final Result VALID = Result.valid(true);
    private static final Result INVALID = Result.valid(false);
    private static final Result FAILED = Result.failed(CHECKING_ERROR);

    abstract static class AnyOfCompletableFutureContractTest {
        @Test
        void timeout() throws Throwable {
            blocking(blocker -> {
                Result blocked = VALID.blocked(blocker);
                CompletableFuture<Result> it = anyOf(blocked);

                assertThrows(TimeoutException.class, () -> fetch(it));

                blocker.countDown();
                assertThat(fetch(it), is(sameInstance(blocked)));
            });
        }

        @Test
        void returnsResultWhichIsValid() throws Throwable {
            assertThat(fetch(anyOf(VALID)), is(VALID));
            assertThat(fetch(anyOf(INVALID, VALID)), is(VALID));
        }

        @Test
        void returnsNullWithEmptyResults() throws Throwable {
            assertThat(fetch(anyOf(new Result[0])), is(nullValue()));
        }

        @Test
        void reportingErrorsWhenAnyOfFuturesFailed() throws Throwable {
            Throwable error = assertThrows(ExecutionException.class, () -> fetch(anyOf(FAILED)));
            assertThat(error.getCause(), is(sameInstance(CHECKING_ERROR)));
        }

        @Test
        void noValidResult() throws Throwable {
            assertNoValidResult(trying(anyOf(INVALID)));
        }

        @Test
        void containingOthersBlockedOnChecking() throws Throwable {
            blocking((blocker) -> {/**/
                assertBlockedBeforeValidResult(trying(anyOf(FAILED.blocked(blocker), VALID)));
            });
        }

        @Test
        void findingStrategy() throws Throwable {
            any[] times = new any[20];
            Result[] results = random(times.length * 3);
            Set<Result> founds = new HashSet<>();

            for (any of : times) founds.add(fetch(anyOf(results)));

            assertFoundResultWithFixedResults(founds);
        }

        protected abstract void assertFoundResultWithFixedResults(Set<Result> results);

        protected abstract void assertNoValidResult(Value<Result> result) throws Exception;

        protected abstract void assertBlockedBeforeValidResult(Value<Result> result) throws Exception;

        public abstract CompletableFuture<Result> anyOf(Result... results);

        private Result[] random(int maxSize) {
            Random random = new Random();
            Result[] results = Stream.generate(() -> Result.valid(random.nextBoolean())).limit(maxSize).toArray(Result[]::new);
            results[results.length - 1] = VALID;
            return results;
        }

        class any {

        }

        private void blocking(Action<CountDownLatch> action) throws Exception {
            CountDownLatch blocking = new CountDownLatch(1);
            try {
                action.apply(blocking);
            } finally {
                blocking.countDown();
            }
        }

        Result fetch(CompletableFuture<Result> future) throws Exception {
            return trying(future).get();
        }

        Value<Result> trying(CompletableFuture<Result> future) {
            return () -> future.get(100, MILLISECONDS);
        }

        interface Action<T> {
            void apply(T t) throws Exception;
        }

        interface Value<T> {
            T get() throws Exception;
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class SyncAnyOfCompletableFutureTest extends AnyOfCompletableFutureContractTest {
        @Override
        protected void assertNoValidResult(Value<Result> result) throws Exception {
            assertThat(result.get(), is(nullValue()));
        }

        @Override
        protected void assertBlockedBeforeValidResult(Value<Result> result) {
            assertThrows(TimeoutException.class, result::get);
        }

        @Override
        protected void assertFoundResultWithFixedResults(Set<Result> results) {
            assertThat(results, hasSize(1));
        }

        @Test
        void stopsWhenTheFirstValidResultHasBeenFound() throws Throwable {
            assertThat(fetch(anyOf(VALID, FAILED)), is(VALID));
        }

        public CompletableFuture<Result> anyOf(Result... results) {
            return anyOf(Instruction::async, results);
        }

        private CompletableFuture<Result> anyOf(Function<Instruction, CompletableFuture<Result>> mapping, Result... results) {
            return anyOf(instructions(results), mapping, Result::isValid);
        }

        private <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> anyOf(List<T> items
                , Function<T, CompletableFuture<R>> promiseMapping
                , Predicate<R> condition) {

            CompletableFuture<R> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
            for (T it : items) {
                result = result.thenCombine(promiseMapping.apply(it), (own, other) -> {
                    if (own != null && condition.test(own)) {
                        return own;
                    }
                    return condition.test(other) ? other : null;
                });
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class AsyncAnyOfCompletableFutureTest extends AnyOfCompletableFutureContractTest {
        @Override
        protected void assertNoValidResult(Value<Result> result) throws Exception {
            assertThrows(TimeoutException.class, result::get);
        }

        @Override
        protected void assertBlockedBeforeValidResult(Value<Result> result) throws Exception {
            assertThat(result.get(), is(VALID));
        }

        @Override
        protected void assertFoundResultWithFixedResults(Set<Result> results) {
            assertThat(results, hasSize(greaterThan(1)));
        }

        public CompletableFuture<Result> anyOf(Result... results) {
            Function<Instruction, CompletableFuture<Result>> mapping = (instruction) -> supplyAsync(() -> {
                instruction.result.isValid(); return instruction.result;
            });
            return anyOf(instructions(results), mapping, Result::isValid);
        }

        private <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> anyOf(List<T> items
                , Function<T, CompletableFuture<R>> promiseMapping
                , Predicate<R> condition) {
            return items.parallelStream()
                    .map(promiseMapping)
                    .map(completeWhenMatching(condition))
                    .reduce(doneWhenAnyCompleted())
                    .orElse(completedFuture(null));
        }

        private <R> Function<CompletableFuture<R>, CompletableFuture<R>> completeWhenMatching(Predicate<R> condition) {
            return origin -> origin.thenCompose(result -> {
                CompletableFuture<R> it = new CompletableFuture<>();
                if (condition.test(result)) {
                    it.complete(result);
                }
                return it;
            });
        }

        private <R> BinaryOperator<CompletableFuture<R>> doneWhenAnyCompleted() {
            return (main, other) -> main.applyToEither(other, Function.identity());
        }
    }

    private static List<Instruction> instructions(Result... results) {
        return stream(results).map(Instruction::new).collect(toList());
    }

    public interface Result {
        boolean isValid();

        static Result valid(boolean valid) {
            return new Result() {
                @Override
                public boolean isValid() {
                    return valid;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return valid ? "valid" : "invalid";
                }
            };
        }

        static Result failed(RuntimeException error) {
            return () -> {
                throw Objects.requireNonNull(error);
            };
        }

        default Result blocked(CountDownLatch blocker) {
            Result result = this;
            return new Result() {
                @Override
                public boolean isValid() {
                    try {
                        blocker.await();
                        return result.isValid();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return result.toString() + " blocked";
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private static class Instruction {
        private Result result;

        public Instruction(Result result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

        public CompletableFuture<Result> async() {
            return supplyAsync(() -> this.result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for for the parallel implementation, but this was not asked, exactly because the instructions have a priority and I want to first one that give a valid result.

Comment: @BaptistePernet not at all, you can choose which one you like.